# Elegant way of finding related fields in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

So I have an instance of Django model ("item") and a list of fields and related fields i want to find. Currently I'm doing this:

```
related_fields = ['customer__name', 'customer__address__postcode', 'date']
for related_field in related_fields:
    sub_item = item
    for part in related_field.split('__'):
        sub_item = getattr(sub_item, part)
    item_fields.append(sub_item)
```

I hope that makes sense, but is this the most efficient way of doing it? Surely there must be a Django utility function somewhere that does this in SQL much more quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`QuerySet.values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list). For example:

```
related_fields = ['customer__name', 'customer__address__postcode', 'date']
item_fields = Item.objects.filter(pk=item).values_list(*related_fields, flat=True)[0]
```